# Why does this for loop print 6 and 10?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS and I stumbled across this. I don't understand why it prints 6 and 10.
Could someone please explain the steps and why I am getting these numbers?

```js
var apple = 1;
for (var apple = 0; apple < 10; apple = apple + 2) {
    
    orange = orange + 1;
}
console.log(orange);
console.log(apple);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the code you provided will throw errors. I am assuming it is:

```
var orange = 1;
for (var apple = 0; apple < 10; apple = apple + 2) {
    
    orange = orange + 1;
}
console.log(orange);
console.log(apple);
```

Here the for loop will run 5 times:

1. `apple = 0` `orange = 1`
2. `apple = 2` `orange = 2`
3. `apple = 4` `orange = 3`
4. `apple = 6` `orange = 4`
5. `apple = 8` `orange = 5`
6. `apple = 10` `orange = 6`

The 6th time it will break as `apple = 10` which is not `< 10`. So the final values are 6 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your for loop, you define apple to be 0. Every time it runs, it sets apple to equal whatever apple is plus 2. So apple starts at 0. After the first loop it is 2, after the second loop it is 4, after the third loop it is 6, after the fourth loop it is 8, and after the fifth loop it is 10. Since apple is no longer less than 10, the loop stops. Therefore, when you print apple, you get 10.

Notice that the loop runs 5 times, so you are adding 1 to orange 5 times. This gives orange a value of 1 + 5 = 6.